# how to find the implementation of a function in linux?

Tags: c, linux, vim, operating-system

Sometimes, I want to know the implementation of a c function. My editor is vim. I have try ctags and cscope, and man.

man 2|3 only tell me how to use a function.

Both ctags and cscope can just find some of the implementation of functions.

They all can't find some functions. especially some system function(calls).

If a function can be use by include some header file, is there any way easily find the implementation of a function,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[select(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) is a [system call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syscall) (but I suggest using [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) instead - google for `C10K problem` to understand why I prefer `poll` over `select`). So it is really implemented inside the [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel). The `libc` contains a small stub function (translating the C argument convention to the syscall convention, then doing the real syscall with e.g. some `SYSENTER` machine instruction). You could look into the source code of [MUSL Libc](http://musl-libc.org/) (I recommend MUSL libc because its source is much easier to read) or the real [Gnu libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) to see that wrapper function.

`FD_SET` is just a macro, defined in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/select.h` and really in `/usr/include/bits/select.h`

But you are very right to try to find out how software functions of Linux are implemented: take advantage that it is [free software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

Actually, the syscall layer is well defined and quite stable (see the [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man page, and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more. Look also for the [Posix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posix) standards). It is much more interesting to study the source code of higher-level libraries using them (e.g. Qt, Gtk, ...).

From an application's point of view, syscalls are elementary "atomic" operations. `strace` is a handy utility to find which syscalls are done by some process (or running program).

Answer (score 2):

You won't get around pulling in the sources of the module providing the function's implementation.

For Linux most of the modules in use are open source, so access to the sources shall be possible.

Where to get the sources from depends on library and/or the distribution in use. This includes the kernel.

There are distributions which may include all sources. [Gentoo](http://www.gentoo.org/) is one of those.

For [Debian](http://www.debian.org) based distros it is easy to pull a package's sources using the `apt-get` tool:

```
$ apt-get source <package-name>
```

Other distros may use other ways to provide sources. Perhaps fellow SO experts might like to comment/answer regarding those.

Comment: Thanks, I want to know the implementation of select(), which do IO multiplexing, and the FD_macros used by it. Is there any way to find it. Thanks again.

Comment: @Yejing: The macros are defined in a `*.h` somewhere under `/usr/include`. Most likley `sys/select.h`. You might like to run `grep FD_ISSET /usr/include/ -rw`.